# Eso-pic and data-tool

Tags: datatool, csv, eso-pic

Csv files can be easier to prepare for the person who is not used to LaTeX syntax. I would like to use a csv file containing

---

### Id, myauthor, mydate, myaddress

> 1. Sebastian, 12.12.2012, XYZ road, XYZ city
> 2. Rose, 12.12.2013,  XYZ road, abc city

---

I have to define a command in such a way that if I provide input of Id, the respective fields in following example should be automatically populated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example
\usepackage[headsep=3cm,top=5cm]{geometry}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \makebox(420,75)[lt]{%
      \footnotesize%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{p{4.5cm}}@{}}%
      \textbf{Author}\newline\myauthor&%
      \textbf{Date of birth}\newline\mydate&%
      \textbf{Address}\newline\myaddress%
      \end{tabular}%
}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\myauthor}{user34083}
\newcommand{\mydate}{December 26, 1997}
\newcommand{\myaddress}{26 Washington Ave., Manhattan, New York.\newline United States of America}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % just for the example

\end{document}
```

Comment: The CSV file doesn't match the headers; can you adjust it?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example
\usepackage[headsep=3cm,top=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{datatool}

% create sample csv file
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Id,myauthor,mydate,myaddress
1,Sebastian,12.12.2012,XYZ road,XYZ city
2,Rose,12.12.2013,XYZ road,abc city
\end{filecontents*}

% load data
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test.csv}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \makebox(420,75)[lt]{%
      \footnotesize%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{p{4.5cm}}@{}}%
      \textbf{Author}\newline\myauthor&%
      \textbf{Date of birth}\newline\mydate&%
      \textbf{Address}\newline\myaddress%
      \end{tabular}%
}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\myauthor}{user34083}
\newcommand{\mydate}{December 26, 1997}
\newcommand{\myaddress}{26 Washington Ave., Manhattan, New York.\newline United States of America}

% Define a command that fetches data for the row with the ID
% given in the argument
\newcommand*{\fetchdata}[1]{%
% fetch the first matching row
   \dtlgetrowforvalue{mydata}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{Id}}{#1}%
% Lookup the required values from this row
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\myauthor}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{myauthor}}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\mydate}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{mydate}}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\myaddress}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{myaddress}}%
}

% fetch data for Id=2
\fetchdata{2}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % just for the example

\end{document}
```

This produces (top part of page only):

[image: Image of resulting text]

**Edit:**

In the above example, the city is in a separate column from the road, so it doesn't appear in the document. If you want both the street and city to be in the `myaddress` column, then remember to use double-quote delimiters in the CSV file for entries containing a comma:

```
Id,myauthor,mydate,myaddress
1,Sebastian,12.12.2012,"XYZ road, XYZ city"
2,Rose,12.12.2013,"XYZ road, abc city"
```

Alternatively, add an extra header and modify `\fetchdata` accordingly. For example, edit the CSV file so that it looks like:

```
Id,myauthor,mydate,myroad,mycity
1,Sebastian,12.12.2012,XYZ road,XYZ city
2,Rose,12.12.2013,XYZ road,abc city
```

and change `\fetchdata` to:

```
\newcommand*{\fetchdata}[1]{%
   \dtlgetrowforvalue{mydata}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{Id}}{#1}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\myauthor}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{myauthor}}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\mydate}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{mydate}}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\myroad}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{myroad}}%
   \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\mycity}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydata}{mycity}}%
   \renewcommand*{\myaddress}{\myroad, \mycity}%
}
```